# Installing postgresql on ubuntu

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu

I get the below error when I'm trying to install Postgres Data Base by running that command on Ubuntu OS  **sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4**

> dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.4 (--configure):
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 2 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   postgresql-contrib-9.4: postgresql-contrib-9.4 depends on
>   postgresql-9.4 (= 9.4.11-1.pgdg16.04+1); however: Package
>   postgresql-9.4 is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing package
>   postgresql-contrib-9.4 (--configure): dependency problems - leaving
>   unconfigured No apport report written because the error message
>   indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. Errors were
>   encountered while processing: postgresql-9.4 postgresql-contrib-9.4 E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 2):

If you tried several solutions, you probably have some leftovers from that tries. 
To start from 'scratch' you have to uninstall everything and cleanup your system before trying anything:

sudo apt-get purge 'postgresql.*'

This will uninstall all packages and remove all config files.
Note: this will also remove all database files from your system.

After that you have to check what repositories you have added to the system. 
Check /etc/apt/sources.list file and every other files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory.

Remove everything related to postgresql and 'pgdg'.

And finally, you can follow official postgresql manual here: 
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have followed what you have said and used the official postgresql manual, still have the same error!.

Comment: Maybe its possible that you have broken some other packages not related to postgresql. I,e perl modules.
Have you tried to do: apt-get update && apt-get upgrade?

Comment: Yes I have. now when I upgrade This error "dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib-9.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.5
 postgresql-contrib-9.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"